# International Physical Activity Questionnaire and cognitive function

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, attention, survey, exercise

I'm looking for research that has examined the link between physical activity (as measured by the International Physical Activity Questionnaire [1] specifically) and cognitive function (any domain is fine - attention, memory etc)

Most research that has examined the link between activity and cognition have been experimental/manipulation studies, but I can't seem to find much correlational work using the IPAQ

I've found a couple of pieces, for example [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23265015) and [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25826160), but the samples are quite specific (elderly and obese)

Can anyone point me to any correlational work that has studied cognitive function of younger populations using this particular questionnaire?

**References**

1. Craig, C. L., Marshall, A. L., Sandstrom, M., Bauman, A. E., Booth, M. L., Ainsworth, B. E., … Oja, P. (2003). International Physical Activity Questionnaire: 12-Country Reliability and Validity. Medicine & Science in Sports & Exercise, 35(8), 1381–1395. https://doi.org/10.1249/01.MSS.0000078924.61453.FB